# Black borders around windows/apps missing from dash after kernel update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel, unity-dash

I'm having some weird issues with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I updated the kernel to 3.18 (or at least I think I did...) using this guide here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-linux-kernel-3-18-ubuntu/

From the section of the guide below I installed `linux-headers-3.18.0-031800_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_all.deb` and then `linux-image-3.18.0-031800-generic_3.18.0-031800.201412071935_amd64.deb`.

> Install / Upgrade to Linux Kernel 3.18 in Ubuntu:
>
> The Ubuntu Kernel Team has made the binary packages of this kernel
>   release, available for download at the link below:
>
> Download Kernel 3.18 (.deb)

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I was attempting to fix sound issues with my ALC1150 sound card. From what I've read the 222issues were fixed in the 3.18 kernel, but now I have black borders around many of my windows and the "Additional Drivers" app is missing (so I can't see if switching the Nvidia drivers will fix the border issue) along with "Software & Updates" and presumably other apps, from the dash when I search for it.

I've restarted my computer since the kernel update and have tried running the update command multiple times to attempt to fix it... I also have "Unity Tweaker Installed" and reset all of those settings to defaults in order to rule that out. I've tried messing with some of the default appearance settings under the system settings, nothing I do seems to have an effect.

My system specs are:

- Gigabyte Z97X-SLI rev 1.0,
- Intel i5-4570s,
- 24GB Crucial Low Profile Memory,
- GTX 770 (Only "Gallium 0.4 on NVE4" is showing up under "About This Computer")

Any idea how I might be able to get rid of these huge black borders around my windows and fix my dash?

--

I think this is the issue, that the kernel was built incorrectly, but I have no idea how to fix it, I really don't want to have to re-install as I've spent all this time configuring my OS exactly how I want, is there a simple fix for this? (Could I just copy my home folder to a flash drive and do a fresh install? Would all my programs work, my VPN settings and user settings work?)

m

```
r@mr-Z97X-SLI:~$ apt-cache showpkg linux-headers
Package: linux-headers
Versions: 
Reverse Depends:    i915-3.19-3.13-dkms, linux-headers  
cmem-mod-dkms,linux-headers  
linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal,linux-headers  
linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal,linux-headers  
sl-modem-dkms,linux-headers   xtables-addons-dkms,linux-headers  
volatility-tools,linux-headers   systemtap,linux-headers  
openswan-modules-source,linux-headers   iscsitarget-dkms,linux-headers
fwts-efi-runtime-dkms,linux-headers   alsa-source,linux-headers  
linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal,linux-headers Dependencies: 
Provides:
Reverse Provides:  linux-headers-3.18.4-031804-generic
3.18.4-031804.201501271243 linux-headers-3.19.0-031900-lowlatency 3.19.0-031900.201502091451 linux-headers-3.19.0-031900-generic 3.19.0-031900.201502091451 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-lowlatency 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic 3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-29-lowlatency 3.16.0-29.39~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-29-generic 3.16.0-29.39~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-28-lowlatency 3.16.0-28.38~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic 3.16.0-28.38~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-26-lowlatency 3.16.0-26.35~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-26-generic 3.16.0-26.35~14.04.1 linux-headers-3.16.0-25-lowlatency 3.16.0-25.33~14.04.2 linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic 3.16.0-25.33~14.04.2 linux-headers-3.13.0-45-lowlatency 3.13.0-45.74 linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic 3.13.0-45.74
linux-headers-3.13.0-44-lowlatency 3.13.0-44.73
linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic 3.13.0-44.73
linux-headers-3.13.0-43-lowlatency 3.13.0-43.72
linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic 3.13.0-43.72
linux-headers-3.13.0-41-lowlatency 3.13.0-41.70
linux-headers-3.13.0-41-generic 3.13.0-41.70
linux-headers-3.13.0-40-lowlatency 3.13.0-40.69
linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic 3.13.0-40.69
linux-headers-3.13.0-39-lowlatency 3.13.0-39.66
linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic 3.13.0-39.66
linux-headers-3.13.0-37-lowlatency 3.13.0-37.64
linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic 3.13.0-37.64
linux-headers-3.13.0-36-lowlatency 3.13.0-36.63
linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic 3.13.0-36.63
linux-headers-3.13.0-35-lowlatency 3.13.0-35.62
linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic 3.13.0-35.62
linux-headers-3.13.0-34-lowlatency 3.13.0-34.60
linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic 3.13.0-34.60
linux-headers-3.13.0-33-lowlatency 3.13.0-33.58
linux-headers-3.13.0-33-generic 3.13.0-33.58
linux-headers-3.13.0-32-lowlatency 3.13.0-32.57
linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic 3.13.0-32.57
linux-headers-3.13.0-30-lowlatency 3.13.0-30.55
linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic 3.13.0-30.55
linux-headers-3.13.0-29-lowlatency 3.13.0-29.53
linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic 3.13.0-29.53
linux-headers-3.13.0-27-lowlatency 3.13.0-27.50
linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic 3.13.0-27.50
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-lowlatency 3.13.0-24.47
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.47
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-lowlatency 3.13.0-24.46
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.46
```

Comment: Just updated to kernel 3.18.4 using this guide:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/upgrade-linux-kernel-3-18-4-ubuntu/

And am still having the same issue.

Comment: So I was updating the kernel incorrectly... Here's how to actually update your kernel (and to the latest version): http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/upgrade-linux-kernel-3-19-ubuntu-14-04/

Cool, now I know how to update my kernel properly! Now to fix the borders...

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu mainline kernel, that integrates well with the package manager and DKMS, is to subscribe to [`ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and install the new Hardware Enablement Stack:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

However the only release with a kernel version ≥3.18 is Vivid, which is currently in pre-release state, so you'll need to subscribe to the `vivid` distribution of that PPA. Then you'll get the default kernel for Vivid with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu vivid'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```